# restrict number with decimals in between

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate whether a number with decimals in between is within the range of 0-255 which allows leading zeroes.

So far I have come up with the regex

```
^0*([1-9][\.\d]|250)*
```

and the example that I have tried it on is 63.32.32.250 however it only grabs the 63, and not the rest of the string.

I thought [\.\d] would include all the periods, however it isn't the case.

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: are you trying to make a regex for IPV4 addresses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for IP Address Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006459/regular-expression-for-ip-address-validation)

Comment: See [*Validate IPv4 address in Java*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667371/validate-ipv4-address-in-java).

Comment: Nope, I'm not really trying to make a regex for IPV4 addresses, just for any random numerical address with 3 decimal points with 4 numbers. I've taken a look at the suggested links, and those regex seem particularly long. Is there a more elegant solution perhaps?

Comment: A numerical adress separated by `.` with values between 0 and 255. Well, this seems pretty close to IPv4 ... you should use the same logic you know. And check SO, there is planty of regex, a range like this is not simple is Regex. But you can split the String and check the numerical value range

Comment: The part in square brackets is a character class. ```[\.\d]``` is one period or one digit. Ignoring the leading 0 thing completely: You're matching 1-9 followed by a period OR another digit. "1." would match. "12" would as well, but wouldn't include the period. "122" wouldn't match at all.

Comment: More elegant solution is not to use a regex. Split with  a dot, parse the numbers, check. Anyway, as Java regex does not support pattern recursion/subroutine calls, you cannot shorten those regexps.

Comment: I see... alright. Thanks for the suggestions everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Federico Piazza's answer is better but if you want to do it manually I would think about using the split function and checking using ><, e.g...

```
String[] numbers = "63.32.32.250".split("\\.");
for(String number: numbers){
   -> parse number string to an int
   -> check its in right range just with ><=
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Split method takes a regex as parameter. you have to escape the dot with `\\.`. If you don't split it your array will contain 12 null values

Comment: @FedericoPiazza it'd be a zero-length array instead, if you used `.`, because trailing empty strings are not returned.

Comment: @AndyTurner, true... thought it was going to split it multiple times

Comment: @FedericoPiazza it would if you call `split(".", -1)`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex for this is not a good idea, you can use [InetAddressValidator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html) like this:

```
InetAddressValidator.getInstance().isValid(YOUR_IP_HERE)
```

Btw, you can use `isValidInet4Address` method as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Works w/ Flaw

To validate IPv4 addresses you would do something like

```
^((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/y5DOhUI30QXukR89)

But this has the vital flaw of not checking if the number is between 1-255

### Works

```
^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/N1ZQXl5kG-sIO1KG)

Answer (score 0):

For one group of digits:

```
^0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

For four groups, repeat:

```
^0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.0*([0-9]{1,2}|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

This will capture four groups.